# Add Identity sequence values to Column ID

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and except first column `(ID)`, all other columns populated with records (more than 10000 records). I want to fill the **ID** column with sequence numbers `(1,2,3,4...)` for all the records.

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I have tried the following statement:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS ID, Name FROM TableName
```

But not able to use the ROW_NUMBER() in UPDATE statement.

How to do that?

Comment: Not really clear : you want to fill ID with incremented values, and than change ID to an Identity column ?

Comment: I have updated expected output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (null,'A'),
    (null,'B'),
    (null,'C'),
    (null,'D'),
    (null,'E')
```

Then update statement like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS rowNbr,
        tbl.*
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
UPDATE CTE
    SET CTE.ID=CTE.rowNbr
```

Then the output from this:

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Will be this:

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter an existing column to be an `IDENTITY`, but you can add a new identity column (provided that there is only 1 identity on the table). Given that your existing `ID` contains all NULL's, why not drop and re-add?

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP Column ID;
GO

Alter Table MyTable Add ID Int Identity(1, 1)
Go
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/831e6/1)